# Arrow disable if there are no more image in the left or right

Tags: jquery, ajax, prototype, bxslider

I use BxSlider carousel to display my gallery image, Lets say that I have nine images and the script is set with  **minSlides: 3** and **maxSlides: 3**, and i am watching image 1-3, then the arrow should be only on the right side, which means i can browse for more pics to the right. then, when i browse the the right and i am watching f.e. image 4,5,6, in this case the arrows should be on boths sides, because there are pics to the left and to the right. BUT, if i browse again to the right and get until image 7,8,9, the the arrow on right side should disappear because there is nothing more to browse to the right. only the left arrow should be shown in this case.

My bxslider script look like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: false,
    pager: false,
    controls: true,
    infiniteLoop:false,
    slideWidth: 125,
    minSlides: 3,
    maxSlides: 3,
    slideMargin: 10,
    adaptiveHeight: true
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the docs: http://bxslider.com/options#hideControlOnEnd

```
hideControlOnEnd: true,
```

---

Protip: use namespacing to allow use of the dollar sign in your code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#bxslider').bxSlider({ ... });
});
```

Comment: perfect thank you so much, is work like a charm :) you have any idea the correct way to give the bx-wrapper the 100% width?

Comment: Please open a new question and show your HTML there.